# Binding hidden fields in formview

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, objectdatasource, formview, hiddenfield

I am trying to use a formview bound to an ObjectDataSource, in the formview I use a couple of hidden fields which hold values required for an insert.

I set the value of these fields server side during a TextChanged event on a devexpress ASPxGridLookup.

However during the Inserting event these fields are present but no value is given.

I am trying to figure out what has happened here and I can see that the hidden fields do not maintain their set values.

Any help would be much appreciated.

thanks.

Kieran

Comment: Provide some markup and code to understand better..that what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the values aren't being reset during the the Page Load.  Not sure if you have any code running there to prepare the page, but I've run into that before.

If you do have code executing on the Page Load, you might try to wrap it in the following If statement.  That will prevent it from being reset when the page load executes prior to your inserting event being raised.

```
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        'your code here...
    End If
```